# How to use MULE ESB pop3 inbound endpoint to listen for unread messages

Tags: java, esb, mule

How to use MULE ESB pop3 inbound endpoint to listen for unread messages? 
I am using MULE 3.3 Version

configuration:

MY POP CONNECTOR:

```
<pop3s:connector name="pop3Connector"
                 defaultProcessMessageAction="RECENT"
                 checkFrequency="1000"
                 deleteReadMessages="false"/>
```

MY INBOUND ENDPOINT:

```
<pop3s:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="pop3Connector" host="pop.gmail.com"
                responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="POP3"
                 password="mypassword" port="995"
                 user="myemailid" />
```

While i run the application the inbound fetches all the available mails from my INBOX.
But i just need the recent unread mails

Comment: Mule version? What values do you use for the `deleteReadMessages`, `moveToFolder` and `defaultProcessMessageAction` of your POP3 connector config? See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/POP3+Transport+Reference#POP3TransportReference-Connectors

Comment: <pop3s:connector name="pop3Connector" defaultProcessMessageAction="RECENT" checkFrequency="1000"  deleteReadMessages="false"/>

Comment: Thanks. Please specify the Mule version and also please clearly state the problem you're facing. Update the above question, don't add comments.